# Is there a way to use reflection to examine an assembly in isolation?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a plugin assembly, that references 3rd party assemblies for the application that it "plugs into". I then have a utility that runs this 3rd party application, passing it the full name of the class, the assembly name and the method in my plugin that it is to run.

I could hardcode these details as string constants in the utility. Instead though, I'd like to obtain them at runtime using reflection. The plugin class implements a specific interface and the method is annotated with a custom attribute. So it ought to be possible I'd have thought. I added a specific reflection class to the plugin and call that to get the details. But it falls over at the (representative) line:

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes() with a FileNotFoundException due to trying to load one of the 3rd party assemblies. Due to licensing rules, I do not want to link the utility directly to these 3rd party assemblies.

So my question is, how do I get a list of classes in my plugin assembly without triggering the attempted loading of other referenced assemblies? Is it possible, or must I resort to my string constants?

Comment: One possible solution might be to use `Mono.Cecil` for inspection instead of reflection

Comment: Why do you want to examine the assembly? What are you going to do with the `Type`s that you get?

Comment: the plan was to iterate over each type to check if it implements an interface. If it does, I then planned to search that type to find the method that is annotated with my custom attribute. These values are then used to call the application with arguments like -exec "<namespace>.<classname>, <assembly>" <methodname>

Comment: Doesn't `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` do this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2s44xz6.aspx

Comment: @Tergiver, Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly that doesn't work. When I tried the ReflectionOnlyLoad route, it give me an excepption with "When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event." :(

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, Mono.Cecil isn't a route I wanted to take, but it looks like I'm running out of options.

Comment: It seems you do have the necessary assemblies (the application wouldn't run otherwise). Why can't you load them into the main application? Also, why isn't this reflection code in the application you're calling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil)

Comment: This isn't the answer I wanted, but it does seem to be the only solution, so I'm marking as the correct one.